# Is it safe to shut down ScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am implementing a service that does some longer running tasks that is emulated by `Thread.sleep(10000)` here. When I ctrl+c the execution I never get the `InterruptedException` that I would expect. I am wondering why.

```
package simple;

import my.util.Now;
import io.dropwizard.lifecycle.Managed;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class EmailSender implements Managed {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailSender.class);
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);

    // Constructor
    public EmailSender() {}

    @Override
    public void start() {
        LOGGER.info("Starting email sender thread: {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Runnable task = () -> {
            LOGGER.info("Running: {} in thread: {}", Now.now(), Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                LOGGER.error("Task is being interrupted: {}", ie.getMessage());
            }
        };
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        LOGGER.info("Stopping email sender thread: {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        executorService.shutdown();

    }
}
```

Is this safe to assume that `executorService.shutdown();` waits till the execution is over for the task this way?

Comment: The docs essentially say it all: [`shutdown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) just prevents the executor from accepting new submissions. You probably wanted [`shutdownNow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()), which interrupts running threads. And no, the latter isn't safe for the same reasons that interrupting threads isn't really safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`shutdown` doesn't terminate currently running tasks, it even executes the ones waiting in the queue.

Use [`shutdownNow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()) if you want to terminate immediately.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this safe to assume that executorService.shutdown(); waits till the execution is over for the task this way?

No. It won't wait for completion of all threads.

Recommended way from oracle documentation page of [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

```
 void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
   pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
   try {
     // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
     if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
       // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
           System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
     // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
     pool.shutdownNow();
     // Preserve interrupt status
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
```

`shutdown():`  Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.

`shutdownNow():`Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.

You can change

```
if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
```

to

```
while (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
Thread.sleep(60000);
```